# C++ Boost Python numpy array initialization

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost

In Python I can initialize an x-length numpy array of negative inf with

```
import numpy as np
...
foo = np.array([np.NINF] * x)
```

where `x` is an int e.g. 42. I'd like to do the same in C++ with Boost.Python. The following obviously won't work:

```
namespace bnp = boost::python::numpy;
...
bnp::ndarray foo = bnp::array({-INFINITY} * x);
```

What are some good ways to do this?

Yes I'm aware of the [Boost.Numpy docs and tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/python/doc/html/numpy/tutorial/ndarray.html) -- they're not great.

More generally, how can I initialize an std vector or array of length x with values -INFINITY?

*UPDATE:*

I'm trying to validate approaches (using an initial loop as suggested in the comments) by then printing to the console with

```
for (auto i=0; i<x; ++i) {
    std::cout << foo[i] << '\n';
}
```

but get the following error: `error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'object_item' (aka 'proxy<boost::python::api::item_policies>'))`. Why won't this work? Is it an issue with trying to access a boost numpy array by index?

Comment: According to the docs, you can construct an array from a python list. Did you try something along the lines of: `bp::list l; l.append(-INFINITY); l *= x; bnp::ndarray foo = bnp::array(l)`? Unfortunately I don't have a build of boost python with numpy support at hand to test it.

Comment: You can use std::fill from the algorithm header to initalize a vector or array

Comment: @Kochoba Could you, please, elaborate on how that applies to the question? From what I found, the most straightforward way to get a `boost::python::list` from say a `std::vector` was an append in a loop. Using `boost::python::numpy::from_data` doesn't seem any more terse than the 4 statements above. In any case, we would be creating a new vector, so we can fill it directly in the constructor. Or did you have something else in mind? What specifically?

Comment: @DanMašek More generally, how can I initialize an std vector or array of length x with values -INFINITY

Comment: @Kochoba OK, although strictly speaking you don't really need `std::fill` to do that in most cases. However, my point is, how does filling any sort of standard c++ container with the appropriate values help in initializing an `boost::python::numpy::ndarray`? Or, in case you didn't mean that, how can we use `std::fill` or some other algorithm, on an instance of that class? Or did you have something else in mind, that I've missed in the documentation and source code of Boost.Python?

Comment: @DanMašek This has been answered in another SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032445/boost-python-vector-to-numpy-array The same thing applies to boost::python::numpy::ndarray

Comment: @DanMašek You can also have a look at this post http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/python/doc/html/numpy/tutorial/fromdata.html on examples on how you can have a union on a C++ array and a boost::python::numpy::ndarray (Basically by passing the pointer to the wrapper class)

Comment: @DanMašek thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying `bpy::list temp_list;`, `for (auto i=0; i<x; ++i) {temp_list.append(-INFINITY);}`, `bnp::ndarray foo = bnp::array(temp_list);`. I'm unsure if this works as expected thought, and have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution (thank you to @DanMašek for the initial idea) and how to validate by printing to the console:

```
bpy::list temp_list;
temp_list.append(-INFINITY);
temp_list *= x;
bnp::ndarray foo = bnp::array(temp_list);
```

where I have x=9. Validate w/

```
std::cout << std::endl << "Python ndarray : " << bpy::extract<char const *>(bpy::str(foo)) << std::endl;
```

You can also use the same `temp_list` to init another Python ndarray:

```
// after initializing bar the same as foo w/ temp_list
bar[0] = 0;
std::cout << std::endl << "Python ndarray : " << bpy::extract<char const *>(bpy::str(bar)) << std::endl;
```

And the resulting print out:

```
Python ndarray : [-inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf]

Python ndarray : [  0. -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf]
```

Comment: Nice. One comment -- since you're setting all the elements of the list to the same value, you can just use the `*` operator, as you would in Python.